# How can I make my question on-topic?

Tags: discussion

I have a question about [Can you escape a contract if a business maltreated its other customers?](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/27498/can-you-escape-a-contract-if-a-business-maltreated-its-other-customers)

[This comment](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/27498/can-you-escape-a-contract-if-a-business-maltreated-its-other-customers#comment48857_27498) recommends

> You need to edit the question to make it generic.

What can I do to make my question generic? Can someone help please?

Answer (score 2):

It's not always possible to bring a question "on-topic."  For example: The referenced question, even if turned into a "hypothetical," probably doesn't admit itself to good answers.  In general: No, you aren't entitled to a refund unless some contract or law permits it.  Your question seems to be asking not whether, in general, airfare is refundable, but whether some specific consideration of "dad's" conditions give him some claim to a refund that otherwise wouldn't be available.

In general, I suspect that any question of the form, "I think a specific situation is unfair, what can I do about it?" is off-topic, if not as a request for specific legal advice, then because without a particular provision of law to address the situation the answer would probably be generic and not law-specific: E.g., "Negotiate a solution, pitch a fit, organize a boycott, lead a movement to enact a law, etc."

Answer (score 1):

Basically, try to remove the specifics about how you got to this point. The question should make sense and be perfectly answerable without knowing your life's story.

If that's not the case, then the question is clearly asking for specific legal advice, which we can't provide. That's a job for your lawyer, not some randos on the internet.